# How to increase size of drop down items of Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can I increase the size of Drop Down Items in Spinner? Its looking too small on my device

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

see image below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to define custom adapter for `Spinner` 
Steps :

1. create custom adapter like list,grid.
2. set your custom adapter to `Spinner`

see this [tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107)

Answer (score 2):

I can increase the dropdown width by using the android:dropDownWidth

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSports"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/questionResponses"
        android:dropDownWidth="150dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter that you have created for spinner add this

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```